# Can't pass extracted string into body object in JMeter

Tags: java, json, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to pass a string extracted from an API response in a subsequent call in JMeter. I am able to extract the object I want (`"thing": "THING"`), store it as variable `$thisThing` and then pass it, but not as a string.

Using this as my body data:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "thing": ${thisThing}
}
```

...results in this request body:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "thing": THING,
}
```

And the API errors out, unexpected token. Looking into post-processing solutions but I can't dig up anything of relevance.

Comment: Add double quotes `"thing": "${thisThing}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JSON Object Literals](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp):

> Keys must be strings, and values must be a valid JSON data type:
>
> - string
> - number
> - object
> - array
> - boolean
> - null

so if this `THING` supposed to be a JSON String - you need to surround it with quotation marks:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "thing": "${thisThing}"
}
```

or amend your [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) configuration to extract the `THING` value along with surrounding quotation marks.

You might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)